# Processing failed [image link] - Feed (OPENCART) Google Merchant Center

Tags: php, schema, opencart

Good Morning.
I'm having problems sending products to Google, it happens that I automatically generate the products through OPENCART and everything is fine, but the images give an error.

The following message appears:
Processing failure [image link]

It happens that when clicking the link of the image, is displayed correctly, follows the print:
http://prntscr.com/o1dd4l

Product Image
https://www.cirurgicaassuncao.com.br/loja/image/catalog/Produtos/Bota-Comfort-Imobilizadora.jpg

I wanted to know why the error occurs.

- I have already changed Htacess to not block Hotlink and the hosting is not blocking either
- I have already removed the cache function from the images in the way it is direct
- I have already programmed the maximum of 720x720 images so as not to make processing difficult
- Their weight is around 100kbps

Nothing worked, what should I do?

Thank you very much in advance.

Processing failure [image link]

Comment: In English, please, or try your question at [pt.so].

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the question.
Can you help me please ?